# Is it possible to reset launchpad layout?

Tags: applications, macos, mac-appstore, launchpad

My launchpad has become very cluttered overtime. I'm wondering if there is a function to reset launchpad like the iOS [reset home screen layout](http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/14/reset-the-home-screen-layout-ios/) feature. Let me know in the comments if you don't understand what I'm asking.

Comment: a related question for users on high sierra can be found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/300109/122152

Answer (score 3):

To reset Launchpad to the default, delete the following file:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Dock/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.db
```

- Where "xxxx..." in the file name is an alphanumeric string.

And then run the following command in a Terminal:

```
 killall Dock
```

The Launchpad is now reset to the default and a new database (.db file) will be created with the default settings.

Note:  If you want to examine the contents of the database you can use an app like [Liya](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/liya/id455484422?mt=12).

Comment: Does this remove all the app icons? I want to be perfectly clear before doing this :)

Comment: @www139, I've tested this on my own system and saw no adverse effects.  One should not just delete a file without having a backup so as to be able to revert to the previous state if needed/wanted. As to  "_Does this remove all the app icons?_", in what context are you referring to? I had my Launchpad set alphabetical using LaunchpadCleaner and when I manually removed the target file and `killall Dock` the Launchpad was reset to having the OS X default apps first as arranged upon first boot and everything I installed since came after the default apps. All icons still showed as I expected.

Comment: Great, that is what I was looking for :)